# Schaltung vs. Schaltungkreis

Tags: meaning, word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

I want to read some book in German language about electronic but i see somewhere translate Schaltung for citcuit and Schaltungkreis for circuit too.

Can someone said what is the different between these two?

Comment: Wikipedia says: "Eine elektrische Schaltung kann aus einem oder mehreren Stromkreisen bestehen".  I suppose "Stromkreis" = "Schaltkreis" but I am not an expert. (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektrische_Schaltung  -- the word "Schaltkreis" is redirected to this, but then the text doesn't mention the word)

Comment: @Alazon: [Apparently not](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74647/schaltung-vs-schaltungkreis#comment177950_74650), as was just explained elsewhere. But SO will not let me undo my upvote for your comment anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The word *der Schaltungskreis* doesn't have an established meaning. Don't use it if you want to be understood. You probably mean *der Schaltkreis*.

So what's the difference between *die Schaltung* and *der Schaltkreis*?

*Die Schaltung* is the umbrella term. Any kind of electrical circuit is a *Schaltung*. In contrast, *der Schaltkreis* is a subdivision inside a larger *Schaltung*. Example:

*In einer Radioschaltung gibt es einen Schaltkreis für den Empfang, einen Schaltkreis für die Senderauswahl, einen Schaltkreis für die Demodulation und einen Schaltkreis für die Leistungsverstärkung des Audiosignals.*

In older books *der Schaltkreis* is also used as an abbreviation of *der integrierte Schaltkreis — integrated circuit — IC*.

---

This use of the ending *-kreis* as a subdivision is pretty common in German. Prominent examples are *der Arbeitskreis — working group*, *die Fachkreise — experts (as a group)*, *der Leserkreis — audience (of a newspaper or author)*, *der Bilanzkreis — accounting grid*, *der Dunstkreis — orbit (of an organisation)*, *der Problemkreis — issue (inside of some larger problem)*, *der Freundeskreis — friends (as an assembly)*, *der Familienkreis — family (as an assembly).*

Comment: No, it's about subdivisions. I'm an electrical engineer. What you mean is a *Stromkreis*.

Comment: Interesting. So the set of all transistors from a Schaltung, or a random portion of a Schaltung that does not form a cycle, would also be called "Schaltkreis"?

Comment: If it's a functional unit, it's a Schaltkreis. There doesn't even need to be an electrical connection. E.g. a photocoupler circuit is *one* Schaltkreis not two.

Comment: Good to know. I will duly replace my previous assumption (for which I quote someone else's [comment on the question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74647/schaltung-vs-schaltungkreis#comment177937_74647), 'I suppose "Stromkreis" = "Schaltkreis" but I am not an expert.', with this newly learned, more definitive definition :)

Comment: Stromkreise are subdivisions inside a Schaltkreis, or a Schaltung.